# Wordpress - All-in-one-seo-pack 2.4.2 broke my site

Tags: wordpress

I have **updated my all-in-one-seo-pack to version 2.4.2** and a specific template page breaks.

```
<!-- /all in one seo pack -->
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//localhost' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//ajax.aspnetcdn.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//load.sumome.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//a.optnmnstr.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="brand &raquo; Feed" href="http://localhost:8001/feed/" />

<!-- optimize -->
... google optimize ...
<!-- end optimize -->

<meta property="og:title" content="Thank you for registering"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<p class="registration-notification">
You will receive the confirmation email shortly.</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-orange fill" href="http://offer.website.com/">Start your free trial</a></p>"/>

<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
```

For some reason, **it adds the post content to the meta og:description**. It happens only on a specific template. Anyone has experienced the same issue? Any solution?

ps: Rolling back could be dangerous if from version I was to new one had db changes, right?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It seems that **while updating to the newest version something got kinda wrong**. In the admin panel, for this specific post, **I was able to see title and description fields with text but counter was 0.**

It seems that the **plugin**, when it does not find any text, instead of leaving the values empty it will **inject the Post.title and Post.description**.

So basically, to **fix the issue** I had just to **updated title and description inputs**.